# find all existing wpf controls

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, controls

Is there the possibility to find out each existing controls from my running (debug mode) wpf application?

I need this, to check if a third party library add new controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for WPF Tree Visualizer. [here is an article explains how to work with](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/05/25/wpf-visualizer-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) when I want to visualize the individual components of a wpf control.